# Nested C array pointer types

Tags: c, pointers, cstring

This seems like a question that should have been answered already somewhere but I can't seem to find something satisfactory. Anyway I need to return from a function something that looks like:

```
{ {"foo", "bar"}, {"baz", "foo"}, {"foo", "bar"} }
```

I am familiar with the use of `argv` and I understand what its types means but for some reason I can't get the type of the above expression correct. There will always be 2 string literals on the innermost part and as such I thought something like either

```
char **s[2] or char *(*s[2])
```

should be what I am after but for some reason I constantly end up with a segfault no matter the permutation I try when I attempt to iterate through and use `printf`. Also the compiler is constantly complaining about incompatible pointer types, excess elements and too many braces. This is the current code:

```
 char *(*s[2]) = { {"foo", "bar"}, {"baz", "spam"}, {"eggs", "ham"} };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are close.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char* s[][2] = { {"foo", "bar"}, {"baz", "spam"}, {"eggs", "ham"} };

    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j ++)
        {
            printf("%s ",s[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
```

The above prints: `foo bar baz spam eggs ham`

Comment: Can you explain the difference? I know pointers aren't the same as arrays but I think I might not have fully grasped the differences. Thanks so much.

Comment: `char* s[][2]` says "I want an array of `s[][2]`'s". `s[][2]` says, I want a character array of any length (the `[]`) in sets of 2 (the `[2]`). What you have written. `char **s[2]` says I want a 2d array of `s[2]`'s or I want a pointer to a 1d array of `s[2]`'s (depending on how you fill it).

Comment: @0x69 That is awesome! And I thought we had to fend for ourselves in C declaration land...

Answer (score 1):

It's simple

```
char *s[3][2] ={ {"foo", "bar"}, {"baz", "spam"}, {"eggs", "ham"} };
```

A little explanation :

```
char *s ; //   |s| ---> "Only one char array or string"
                          ______
char *s[] ; //  |s| ---> |_s[0]_|--> 1st pointer to char array --> "1st string"
                         |_s[1]_|--> 2nd pointer to char array --> "2nd string"
                         |_s[2]_|--> 3rd pointer to char array --> "3rd string"

                          ___                                __
char *s[][] ;// |s| ---> |___|--> 1st pointer to pointer -->|__|-->"1st string"                                                                  
                                                            |__|-->"2nd string"                                                                           
                         ____                                __            
                         |___|--> 2nd pointer to pointer -->|__|-->"1st string"                                                                  
                                                            |__|-->"2nd string"
                         ____                                __             
                         |___|--> 3rd pointer to pointer -->|__|-->"1st string"                                                                  
                                                            |__|-->"2nd string"
```

Comment: i understand that this works but what i don't get is how this differs from char **s[]. why does that fail while yours works?

Comment: char **s[] is an array of pointers to pointers to char. here it's one dimensional array of of char ** pointers , but char*[][] is a 2-D array of char*

Answer (score 0):

```
char *s[][2] = { {"foo", "bar"}, {"baz", "spam"}, {"eggs", "ham"} };


cout<<s[1][0];
```

would print `baz`

Comment: @dreamriver Has nothing to do with RO memory. Also it dynamic allocation would work.